# Assigning zero to random cells in a pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, pandas

I am trying to assign `0` to random cells in a one dimensional `pandas.DataFrame`. 
The below code is the best way I could think of doing this, however I believe there may be a neater approach to this problem.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from random import randint


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20, size=(10, 1)), columns=list('A'))
col_size = len(df.columns)
row_size = len(df.index)
df[df.columns[randint(0, col_size-1)]][randint(0, row_size-1)] = 0
```

Could someone please review and suggest if this is a good approach or there are better ways to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, you are only setting a single cell to zero. If this is what you want, then your solution works well. However, if you want to randomly set cells to be 0, then the solutions below might be better.
For an arbitrary dimensional df:

```
# Create Random Mask
rand_zero_one_mask = np.random.randint(2, size=df.shape)
# Fill df with 0 where mask is 0
df = df.where(rand_zero_one_mask==0, 0)
```

Note: [df.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) is not to be confused with [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)